# Password required to logout?

Tags: xubuntu, logout

Fresh install of Xubuntu 14.04.1 32 bit.

When I try to restart or shut down I am asked for a password in order to proceed.

However when I provide a password it is not accepted.

Is there a setting that can be changed to stop the request for a password?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe in 'Applications Menu > System > Users and Groups' you can find something. (Iam not sure, not using ubuntu anymore)

Comment: Are you the admin user of this system?